# return a list as JSON from web2py

Tags: python, json, list, web2py

Is there any way to return a list as a JSON list from web2py?

when I hit my route ending in `.json`, web2py converts dictionaries into valid JSON. If the return value is a list however, it behaves unexpectedly

```
return ["test", "test"]
```

displays

```
testtest
```

and

```
return [dict(test="test"), dict(test="test")]
```

breaks it completely (chrome complains with ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING). The expect behaviour is obviously the following valid JSON strings respectively:

```
["test", "test"]
```

and

```
[{"test":"test"}, {"test":"test"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

registering a json service with the `@service.json` decorator and calling it with `app/controller/call/json/method' gave me the behaviour I expected:

```
def f():
    return ["test1", "test2"]

def call():
    return service()
```

The response body is

```
["test1", "test2"]
```

with content-type set to json

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return a JSON response, your function must either return JSON or trigger the execution of a view that will produce JSON. In web2py, a view will only be executed if a controller function returns a dictionary, so your function will not result in a view being executed (as it does not return a dictionary). If your function did return a dictionary, you would still need to have a `.json` view defined, or explicitly enable the `generic.json` view via `response.generic_patterns` (though `generic.json` would not actually be suitable in your case, as it converts the entire dictionary returned by the function to JSON -- so you could not use it to output only a list).

The simplest solution is just to output JSON directly:

```
    import json
    ...
    return json.dumps(['test', 'test'])
```

or even more simply:

```
    return response.json(['test', 'test'])
```