# Why don't web2py json services treat lists properly?

Tags: python, json, list, web2py

The following works for json whose outermost container is an object like `{ ... }`

```
@service.json
def index():
    data = request.vars
    #fields are now accessible via data["fieldname"] or data.fieldname
    #processing must be done to turn Storage object into dict()
    return data_as_dict
```

If you post a list however, it does not work

POST:

```
[
    {"test": 1}
]
```

`data` will be an empty Storage object and `data[0]` will be `None`

The workaround is simple:

```
@service.json      #so output is still returned as json
def index():
    data = json.loads(request.body.read())
    return data
```

`data` is now a dict in cases of object style JSON (easier to work with than a Storage object imo) and a native list when the JSON is a list.

My question is why is this not the default behaviour? Why should a JSON service not accept valid JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @service.json decorator simply registers a function so it can be accessed via a controller that returns a `Service` object. The decorator ensures that the service controller returns a JSON *response* when the decorated function is called, but it does nothing regarding the processing of JSON *input*.

In any case, your problem is not with the `@service.json` decorator but with a misunderstanding regarding `request.vars`. `request.vars` is a dictionary-like object that is populated with keys and values from the query string and/or the request body (if the request body includes form variables or a JSON object of keys and values). It is not intended to simply be a copy of any arbitrary data structure that is posted in the request body. So, if you post a JSON array in the request body, it would not make sense to copy that array to `request.vars`, as it is not the appropriate type of data structure. If you want to post a JSON array, the correct way to process it is to read the request body, as you have done.

Also, note that because your `index` function does not take any arguments and therefore does not take advantage of the `@service` decorator's ability to map parameters from the HTTP request into function arguments, you could simplify your code by foregoing the `@service` decorator and accessing the `index` function more directly:

```
def index():
    data = json.loads(request.body.read())
    return data
```

Assuming `index` is in the default.py controller, you could post JSON to `/yourapp/default/index.json` (note the `.json` extension), and you will get back a JSON response.

Comment: 1) I don't know what an RPC service is, but I assumed thats what the `@service.jsonrpc` decorator is for  2) if the only "var" POSTed is a json list, what would be wrong with `request.vars` being said list  3) I am accessing it via `/call/json/`  4) when would it be appropriate to use then? the reason I used it in the first place is because it simplifies parsing json (in cases besides this), formats my returned value as json, and sets the content-type appropriately with no extra code

Comment: also, in a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430152/return-a-list-as-json-from-web2py) of mine that you answered, registering the method as a json service ended up solving the problem

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify some issues. (1) The `@service.jsonrpc` decorator is for interacting with a remote procedure call client that specifically implements the JSON-RPC protocol. The `@service.json` decorator, on the other hand, allows for remote procedure calls via simple HTTP requests (putting the parameters in the URL path, query string, and/or request body). See the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#Remote-procedure-calls). (2) As noted, `request.vars` is a dictionary-like object, so it cannot be a list.

Comment: (3) & (4) `/call/json/` is especially useful when you are calling a function that takes arguments and you want to pass those arguments via the URL (or optionally via keys/values in the request body). You can use it in this case as well, but there are other options that may be simpler.

Comment: thanks for the clarification on `request.vars`. I still find it interesting that using the decorator (if you refer to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430152/return-a-list-as-json-from-web2py) I linked) is the only way to return a list as json directly. And concerning Storage, it does a poor job inheriting if I can return a dict but not a Storage (returning Storage in this case breaks the code)

Comment: If a function returns a Python object, the framework has no way of knowing you want it converted to JSON without specifying that somehow. The framework provides several mechanisms for returning JSON, including the very simple `return response.json(your_python_object)`. Regarding `Storage`, the definition starts with `class Storage(dict)`, so if it does a "poor job inheriting," I suppose the problem lies with the Python language.

Comment: No need to get defensive, but why does calling a function as a JSON service behave differently than accessing the method directly with `.json` appended? They both explicitly tell the framework that I "want it converted to JSON". What possible benefit is there in the (imo broken) behavior displayed by my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430152/return-a-list-as-json-from-web2py)? Regarding Storage, in any other language if A inherits from B, you can use A anywhere you can use B. All I am saying is this is not the case with Storage and to me, that makes it inconvenient.

Comment: Not being defensive, just trying to explain how it works. Specifying the `.json` extension simply determines what view to execute, but views are only executed when controllers return dictionaries, so that is not suitable for your case. Nothing is broken. Regarding inheritance, note that the inheriting class can always override some behavior of the inherited class, which means you may not be able to use instances of the two classes interchangeably in all circumstances. If you would like to further discuss the web2py API, I suggest starting a discussion on the Google Group.